# In Django template, image is not displayed correctly

Tags: html, django, image, templates

I have model class with fields current_value and previous_value.
And then, in template used by listview, inside loop i have code like this:

```
{% if data.current_value < data.previous_value %}
    <img src="{% static 'app1/negative.png' %}" width="40" height="40">
    <h1>Price down</h1>
{% elif data.current_value > data.previous_value %}
    <img src="{% static 'app1/positive.png' %}" width="40" height="40">
    <h1>Price up</h1>
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'app1/neutral.png' %}" width="40" height="40">
    <h1>Price the same</h1>
{% endif %}
```

H1 text is displayed correctly, image is not. More specific - image for 'else' condition i believe is always ok, but for 'if' and 'elif' is displaying the same picture (one of them).

Confusing and infuriating. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the `h1` text is displaying correctly for all branches of this template, but some of the images are the same then the most likely problem is that the image files are the same image, but with different filenames.

Comment: No, they are not. I have checked it many times and I have checked it now.

Comment: What about accessing fields? Both curent_value, and previous_value are models.FloatField(). Mayby i should fetch the value of those fields in different way?

Comment: Did you check what image is being rendered via a browser's developer tools and the inspection tool? Otherwise, please post your entire template and an example context that the template is rendered with. It's not possible to answer your question definitely (outside of my original answer) without more information.

Comment: The reason being, if your `h1` elements are being rendered correctly, that means your logical branches are correct and the problem lies with the `img` tag specifically.

Comment: I was gone for a while, reloaded page (without any code change) and suddenly it is displayed properly. In my app current_value and previous_value are changing quite commonly. Is it possibly that web browser is caching those data?

Comment: Nope. The images might have been cached though.